# How to load the entire database without knowing its field names?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Is it possible to read a database through php without knowing the fields names? So it'll be like:

1.Fetching the result array of the table "myTable".

2.Count how many fields are inside each row.

3.Make loop to create the html table and echo the value.

normally we know the fields names of the table, so it's easy to read. What if you don't know the fields name?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM MyTable");
$rows_count = mysql_num_rows($res);
echo '<table>';
for($i=0; $i<$rows_count; $i++)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
    for($r=0;$r<count($row);$r++)
    {
        echo '<td>';
        echo $row[$r];
        echo '</td>';   
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `*` to target all fields:

```
select * from myTable
```

If you have more than 1 table, you can prefix `*` with table's name:

```
select
    another_table.*
from
    my_table
    left join another_table on another_table.id = my_table.another_table_id;
```

Alternatively, you can use `show fields in myTable` or `show full fields in myTable` to get only the list of fields (without data).

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

//connection variables
$host = "";
$database = "";
$user = "";
$pass = "";

//connection to the database
mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass)
or die ('cannot connect to the database: ' . mysql_error());

//select the database
mysql_select_db($database)
or die ('cannot select database: ' . mysql_error());

//loop to show all the tables and fields
$loop = mysql_query("SHOW tables FROM $database")
or die ('cannot select tables');

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($loop))
{

echo "
<table cellpadding=2 cellspacing=2 border=0 width=75%>
<tr bgcolor=#666666>
<td colspan=5><center><b><font color=#FFFFFF>” . $row[0] . “</font></center></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Field</td><td>Type</td><td>Key</td><td>Default</td><td>Extra</td>
</tr>";

$i = 0;

$loop2 = mysql_query("SHOW columns FROM " . $row[0])
or die ('cannot select table fields');

while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($loop2))
{
echo "<tr ";
if ($i % 2 == 0)
echo "bgcolor=#CCCCCC";
echo "><td>" . $row2[0] . "</td><td>" . $row2[1] . "</td><td>" . $row2[2] . "</td><td>" . $row2[3] . "</td><td>" . $row2[4] . "</td></tr>";
$i++;
}
echo "</table><br/><br/>";

}
?>
```

Source :http://jadendreamer.wordpress.com/2009/01/13/print-all-mysql-database-tables-fields-using-php/

Answer (score 1):

you can:

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`, `TABLE_NAME`
FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS`
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's quick and dirty script to get entire table data without knowing it's fields:

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `mysql`.`tables_priv`";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
$tableText = "<table></table>";
$tableHeader = array();
$tableContent = '';
$tableHeaderSet = false;
while( false !== ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)))
{
    if(false == $tableHeaderSet)
    {
        $tableHeaderText = "<tr>";
        foreach( $r as $key=>$val)
        {
            $tableHeader[$key] = $key;
            $tableHeaderText .= "<th>$key</th>";
        }
        $tableHeaderText .= "</tr>";

    }
    $tableHeaderSet = true;
    $tableContent .= "<tr>";
    foreach( $tableHeader as $fieldName)
    {
        $tableContent .= "<td>" . $r[ $fieldName ] . "</td>";
    }
    $tableContent .= "</tr>";

}

echo "<table>{$tableHeaderText}{$tableContent}</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use system tables. In Oracle DB, for example, table ALL_TAB_COLUMNS contains info about columns of user's tables, views and clusters.